# Why do I get "405 - Method Not Allowed" when trying to set bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used a REST API call to successfully create a bucket.  I then try to set a bucket policy on the bucket using the same API keys used to create it.  Here is the policy:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ea_mytestbuckect/*"
    }
]
```

}

But it returns a **405 - Method Not Allowed** message.

Now when I go to the AWS S3 Web console (see screen shot) and check out the bucket permissions, it show **me** as the owner, with my account name being **Mark Schenkel**.  And for **grantee** it shows **mjschenkel**.

Is there a difference between **me** and **mjschenkel**?  I kind of seems like I have two accounts at play here.

[image]

Comment: `Me` and `mjschenkel` are the same user, I get a similar list in the AWS Console for my buckets. According to the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTpolicy.html), `405 Method Not Allowed` is returned when you try to set a bucket policy on a bucket that you don't own, but for which you have the `PutBucketPolicy` permission. However, this shouldn't be your case. Try to post this question on the AWS support forums and maybe someone from AWS will look into it to make sure it's not a S3 bug specific to your account/bucket.